# Flow analysis for android

Tags: java, android, soot

Is there a control flow graph generator for Android applications. (preferrably open source) I wish to do some flow analysis on applications. But I could not find any such static analyzer.

If there is no such software, can **soot** be extended to do the static analysis for Android app. Some pointers on how to do so (especially handling multiple entry points and asynchronous calls to onPause, onDestroy etc. while making Control Flow Graph)  will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Androguard](https://code.google.com/p/androguard/wiki/RE) to generate CFG. Other way is to decompile the app to smali using apktool and write our own CFG generator.

Answer (score 0):

DDMS? http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html
See also: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: I need to make Control Flow graph of the applications. Neither of those tools appear to make one.