# Control Flow Analysis of Android APK or Android Source Code

Tags: android, control-flow-graph, soot

I want to do control and data flow analysis of android app for which I need to create CFG. I have tried soot to make it but all I get is jimple and other middle level intermediate language code.
How make a CFG with soot and even if I get it someway, can anyone point me how to analyze it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ask on the Soot mailing list? Should be the better source for information.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the answer provided in the below link. You can use off the shelf frameworks like androguard.

[CFG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653260/flow-analysis-for-android/15506660#15506660)